# Models disappearing when camera moves DirectX

Tags: c++, model, camera, directx

I am trying to move a camera around a scene and update the models in the scene.  I have managed to get this to work with bitmap rendering.  However, whenever I move the camera when I am rendering a model in the scene, the model will only be visible when the camera is in it's original position:  if the camera is moved at all, then the model disappears.  To clarify, the model is being rendered (it's a 2D plane) when the camera has not moved.  As soon as I trigger a camera movement, the model does not appear on the screen.  Here is my graphics class, camera class and model class:

Graphics:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: graphicsclass.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "graphicsclass.h"


GraphicsClass::GraphicsClass()
{
    m_D3D = 0;
    m_Camera = 0;
    m_Model = 0;
    m_TextureShader = 0;
    m_Bitmap = 0;
    m_Text = 0;
}


GraphicsClass::GraphicsClass(const GraphicsClass& other)
{
}


GraphicsClass::~GraphicsClass()
{
}


bool GraphicsClass::Initialize(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, HWND hwnd)
{
    bool result;
    D3DXMATRIX baseViewMatrix;

    // Create the Direct3D object.
    m_D3D = new D3DClass;
    if(!m_D3D)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the Direct3D object.
    result = m_D3D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, VSYNC_ENABLED, hwnd, FULL_SCREEN, SCREEN_DEPTH, SCREEN_NEAR);
    if(!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize Direct3D.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Create the camera object.
    m_Camera = new CameraClass;
    if(!m_Camera)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Initialize a base view matrix with the camera for 2D user interface rendering.
    m_Camera->SetPosition(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    m_Camera->Render();
    m_Camera->GetViewMatrix(baseViewMatrix);

    //Create the text object.
    m_Text = new TextClass;
    if(!m_Text)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Initialize the text object.
    result = m_Text->Initialize(m_D3D->GetDevice(), hwnd, screenWidth, screenHeight, baseViewMatrix);
    if(!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize the text object.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Set the initial position of the camera.
    m_Camera->SetPosition(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f);

    // Create the model object.
    m_Model = new ModelClass;
    if(!m_Model)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the model object.
    result = m_Model->Initialize(m_D3D->GetDevice(), L"../Engine/data/baseLevel.dds");
    if(!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize the model object.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Create the texture shader object.
    m_TextureShader = new TextureShaderClass;
    if(!m_TextureShader)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the texture shader object.
    result = m_TextureShader->Initialize(m_D3D->GetDevice(), hwnd);
    if(!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize the texture shader object.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    //Create the bitmap object.
    m_Bitmap = new BitmapClass;
    if(!m_Bitmap)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Initialize the bitmap object.
    result = m_Bitmap->Initialize(m_D3D->GetDevice(), screenWidth, screenHeight, L"../Engine/data/baselevel.dds", 2048, 2048);
    if(!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize the bitmap object.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


void GraphicsClass::Shutdown()
{
    //Release the text object.
    if(m_Text)
    {
        m_Text->Shutdown();
        delete m_Text;
        m_Text = 0;
    }

    //Release the bitmap object.
    if(m_Bitmap)
    {
        m_Bitmap->Shutdown();
        delete m_Bitmap;
        m_Bitmap = 0;
    }

    // Release the texture shader object.
    if(m_TextureShader)
    {
        m_TextureShader->Shutdown();
        delete m_TextureShader;
        m_TextureShader = 0;
    }

    // Release the model object.
    if(m_Model)
    {
        m_Model->Shutdown();
        delete m_Model;
        m_Model = 0;
    }

    // Release the camera object.
    if(m_Camera)
    {
        delete m_Camera;
        m_Camera = 0;
    }

    // Release the D3D object.
    if(m_D3D)
    {
        m_D3D->Shutdown();
        delete m_D3D;
        m_D3D = 0;
    }

    return;
}


bool GraphicsClass::Frame(int mouseX, int mouseY, int cameraX, int cameraY)
{
    bool result;

    //set the location of the mouse.
    result = m_Text->SetMousePosition(mouseX, mouseY);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Set the position of the camera.
    m_Camera->SetPosition(cameraX, cameraY, -1.0f);

    // Render the graphics scene.
    result = Render();
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool GraphicsClass::Render()
{
    D3DXMATRIX worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, orthoMatrix;
    bool result;


    // Clear the buffers to begin the scene.
    m_D3D->BeginScene(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Generate the view matrix based on the camera's position.
    m_Camera->Render();

    // Get the world, view, and projection matrices from the camera and d3d objects.
    m_Camera->GetViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
    m_D3D->GetWorldMatrix(worldMatrix);
    m_D3D->GetProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
    m_D3D->GetOrthoMatrix(orthoMatrix);

    //Turn Z buffer off to begin all 2D rendering.
    m_D3D->TurnZBufferOff();

    /*//Render the text strings.
    m_Text->Render(m_D3D->GetDevice(), worldMatrix, orthoMatrix);

    //Put the bitmap vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
    result = m_Bitmap->Render(m_D3D->GetDevice(), 0, 0);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Render the bitmap using the texture shader.
    m_TextureShader->Render(m_D3D->GetDevice(), m_Bitmap->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, viewMatrix, orthoMatrix, m_Bitmap->GetTexture());
    */
    //Turn the z buffer back on now that all 2D rendering has completed.
    m_D3D->TurnZBufferOn();

    // Put the model vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
    m_Model->Render(m_D3D->GetDevice());

    // Render the model using the texture shader.
    m_TextureShader->Render(m_D3D->GetDevice(), m_Model->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, m_Model->GetTexture());

    // Present the rendered scene to the screen.
    m_D3D->EndScene();

    return true;
}
```

Model:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: modelclass.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "modelclass.h"


ModelClass::ModelClass()
{
    m_vertexBuffer = 0;
    m_indexBuffer = 0;
    m_Texture = 0;
}


ModelClass::ModelClass(const ModelClass& other)
{
}


ModelClass::~ModelClass()
{
}


bool ModelClass::Initialize(ID3D10Device* device, WCHAR* textureFilename)
{
    bool result;


    // Initialize the vertex and index buffer that hold the geometry for the triangle.
    result = InitializeBuffers(device);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Load the texture for this model.
    result = LoadTexture(device, textureFilename);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


void ModelClass::Shutdown()
{
    // Release the model texture.
    ReleaseTexture();

    // Release the vertex and index buffers.
    ShutdownBuffers();

    return;
}


void ModelClass::Render(ID3D10Device* device)
{
    // Put the vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
    RenderBuffers(device);

    return;
}


int ModelClass::GetIndexCount()
{
    return m_indexCount;
}


ID3D10ShaderResourceView* ModelClass::GetTexture()
{
    return m_Texture->GetTexture();
}


bool ModelClass::InitializeBuffers(ID3D10Device* device)
{
    VertexType* vertices;
    unsigned long* indices;
    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc, indexBufferDesc;
    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexData, indexData;
    HRESULT result;


    // Set the number of vertices in the vertex array.
    m_vertexCount = 6;

    // Set the number of indices in the index array.
    m_indexCount = 6;

    // Create the vertex array.
    vertices = new VertexType[m_vertexCount];
    if(!vertices)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create the index array.
    indices = new unsigned long[m_indexCount];
    if(!indices)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Load the vertex array with data.
    vertices[0].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom left.
    vertices[0].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);

    vertices[1].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Top left.
    vertices[1].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    vertices[2].position = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // top right.
    vertices[2].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);

    vertices[3].position = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // top right.
    vertices[3].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);

    vertices[4].position = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // bottom right.
    vertices[4].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    vertices[5].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);  // Bottom left.
    vertices[5].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Load the index array with data.
    indices[0] = 0;  
    indices[1] = 1;  
    indices[2] = 2;  
    indices[3] = 3;
    indices[4] = 4;
    indices[5] = 5;

    // Set up the description of the vertex buffer.
    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexType) * m_vertexCount;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    // Give the subresource structure a pointer to the vertex data.
    vertexData.pSysMem = vertices;

    // Now finally create the vertex buffer.
    result = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexData, &m_vertexBuffer);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Set up the description of the index buffer.
    indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned long) * m_indexCount;
    indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    // Give the subresource structure a pointer to the index data.
    indexData.pSysMem = indices;

    // Create the index buffer.
    result = device->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &indexData, &m_indexBuffer);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Release the arrays now that the vertex and index buffers have been created and loaded.
    delete [] vertices;
    vertices = 0;

    delete [] indices;
    indices = 0;

    return true;
}


void ModelClass::ShutdownBuffers()
{
    // Release the index buffer.
    if(m_indexBuffer)
    {
        m_indexBuffer->Release();
        m_indexBuffer = 0;
    }

    // Release the vertex buffer.
    if(m_vertexBuffer)
    {
        m_vertexBuffer->Release();
        m_vertexBuffer = 0;
    }

    return;
}


void ModelClass::RenderBuffers(ID3D10Device* device)
{
    unsigned int stride;
    unsigned int offset;


    // Set vertex buffer stride and offset.
    stride = sizeof(VertexType); 
    offset = 0;

    // Set the vertex buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be rendered.
    device->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // Set the index buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be rendered.
    device->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    // Set the type of primitive that should be rendered from this vertex buffer, in this case triangles.
    device->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    return;
}


bool ModelClass::LoadTexture(ID3D10Device* device, WCHAR* filename)
{
    bool result;


    // Create the texture object.
    m_Texture = new TextureClass;
    if(!m_Texture)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the texture object.
    result = m_Texture->Initialize(device, filename);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


void ModelClass::ReleaseTexture()
{
    // Release the texture object.
    if(m_Texture)
    {
        m_Texture->Shutdown();
        delete m_Texture;
        m_Texture = 0;
    }

    return;
}
```

Camera:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: cameraclass.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "cameraclass.h"


CameraClass::CameraClass()
{
    m_positionX = 0.0f;
    m_positionY = 0.0f;
    m_positionZ = 0.0f;

    m_rotationX = 0.0f;
    m_rotationY = 0.0f;
    m_rotationZ = 0.0f;
}


CameraClass::CameraClass(const CameraClass& other)
{
}


CameraClass::~CameraClass()
{
}


void CameraClass::SetPosition(float x, float y, float z)
{
    m_positionX = x;
    m_positionY = y;
    m_positionZ = z;
    return;
}


void CameraClass::SetRotation(float x, float y, float z)
{
    m_rotationX = x;
    m_rotationY = y;
    m_rotationZ = z;
    return;
}


D3DXVECTOR3 CameraClass::GetPosition()
{
    return D3DXVECTOR3(m_positionX, m_positionY, m_positionZ);
}


D3DXVECTOR3 CameraClass::GetRotation()
{
    return D3DXVECTOR3(m_rotationX, m_rotationY, m_rotationZ);
}


void CameraClass::Render()
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 up, position, lookAt;
    float yaw, pitch, roll;
    D3DXMATRIX rotationMatrix;


    // Setup the vector that points upwards.
    up.x = 0.0f;
    up.y = 1.0f;
    up.z = 0.0f;

    // Setup the position of the camera in the world.
    position.x = m_positionX;
    position.y = m_positionY;
    position.z = m_positionZ;

    // Setup where the camera is looking by default.
    lookAt.x = 0.0f;
    lookAt.y = 0.0f;
    lookAt.z = 1.0f;

    // Set the yaw (Y axis), pitch (X axis), and roll (Z axis) rotations in radians.
    pitch = m_rotationX * 0.0174532925f;
    yaw   = m_rotationY * 0.0174532925f;
    roll  = m_rotationZ * 0.0174532925f;

    // Create the rotation matrix from the yaw, pitch, and roll values.
    D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&rotationMatrix, yaw, pitch, roll);

    // Transform the lookAt and up vector by the rotation matrix so the view is correctly rotated at the origin.
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&lookAt, &lookAt, &rotationMatrix);
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&up, &up, &rotationMatrix);

    // Translate the rotated camera position to the location of the viewer.
    lookAt = position + lookAt;

    // Finally create the view matrix from the three updated vectors.
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&m_viewMatrix, &position, &lookAt, &up);

    return;
}


void CameraClass::GetViewMatrix(D3DXMATRIX& viewMatrix)
{
    viewMatrix = m_viewMatrix;
    return;
}
```

Place where I move my camera:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: systemclass.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "systemclass.h"

SystemClass::SystemClass()
{
    m_Input = 0;
    m_Graphics = 0;
    camX = 0;
    camY = 0;
    m_Sound = 0;
}


SystemClass::SystemClass(const SystemClass& other)
{
}


SystemClass::~SystemClass()
{
}


bool SystemClass::Initialize()
{
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    bool result;


    // Initialize the width and height of the screen to zero before sending the variables into the function.
    screenWidth = 0;
    screenHeight = 0;

    // Initialize the windows api.
    InitializeWindows(screenWidth, screenHeight);

    // Create the input object.  This object will be used to handle reading the keyboard input from the user.
    m_Input = new InputClass;
    if(!m_Input)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the input object.
    result = m_Input->Initialize(m_hinstance, m_hwnd, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    if(!result)
    {
        MessageBox(m_hwnd, L"Could not initialize the input object.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Create the graphics object.  This object will handle rendering all the graphics for this application.
    m_Graphics = new GraphicsClass;
    if(!m_Graphics)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the graphics object.
    result = m_Graphics->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, m_hwnd);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Create the sound object.
    m_Sound = new SoundClass;
    if(!m_Sound)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Initialize the sound object.
    result = m_Sound->Initialize(m_hwnd);
    if(!result)
    {
        MessageBox(m_hwnd, L"Could not initialize Direct Sound.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


void SystemClass::Shutdown()
{
    //Release the sound object.
    if(m_Sound)
    {
        m_Sound->Shutdown();
        delete m_Sound;
        m_Sound = 0;
    }

    // Release the graphics object.
    if(m_Graphics)
    {
        m_Graphics->Shutdown();
        delete m_Graphics;
        m_Graphics = 0;
    }

    // Release the input object.
    if(m_Input)
    {
        m_Input->Shutdown();
        delete m_Input;
        m_Input = 0;
    }

    // Shutdown the window.
    ShutdownWindows();

    return;
}


void SystemClass::Run()
{
    MSG msg;
    bool done, result;


    // Initialize the message structure.
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));

    // Loop until there is a quit message from the window or the user.
    done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        // Handle the windows messages.
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        // If windows signals to end the application then exit out.
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise do the frame processing.
            result = Frame();
            if(!result)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        //Check if the user pressed escape and wants to quit.
        if(m_Input->IsEscapePressed())
        {
            done = true;
        }
        if(m_Input->IsWPressed())
        {
            D3DXVECTOR3 position = m_Graphics->m_Camera->GetPosition();
            camY = position.y + 2;

        }
        if(m_Input->IsAPressed())
        {
            D3DXVECTOR3 position = m_Graphics->m_Camera->GetPosition();
            camX = position.x - 2;
        }
        if(m_Input->IsSPressed())
        {
            D3DXVECTOR3 position = m_Graphics->m_Camera->GetPosition();
            camY = position.y - 2;
        }
        if(m_Input->IsDPressed())
        {
            D3DXVECTOR3 position = m_Graphics->m_Camera->GetPosition();
            camX = position.x + 2;
        }

    }

    return;
}


bool SystemClass::Frame()
{
    bool result;
    int mouseX, mouseY;

    //Do the frame processing.
    result = m_Input->Frame();
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Get the location of the mouse from the input object.
    m_Input->GetMouseLocation(mouseX, mouseY);

    // Do the frame processing for the graphics object.
    result = m_Graphics->Frame(mouseX, mouseY, camX, camY);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    result = m_Graphics->Render();
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK SystemClass::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
}


void SystemClass::InitializeWindows(int& screenWidth, int& screenHeight)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
    int posX, posY;


    // Get an external pointer to this object.  
    ApplicationHandle = this;

    // Get the instance of this application.
    m_hinstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // Give the application a name.
    m_applicationName = L"Engine";

    // Setup the windows class with default settings.
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = m_hinstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm       = wc.hIcon;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = m_applicationName;
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    // Register the window class.
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Determine the resolution of the clients desktop screen.
    screenWidth  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    // Setup the screen settings depending on whether it is running in full screen or in windowed mode.
    if(FULL_SCREEN)
    {
        // If full screen set the screen to maximum size of the users desktop and 32bit.
        memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize       = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth  = (unsigned long)screenWidth;
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = (unsigned long)screenHeight;
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = 32;         
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields     = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        // Change the display settings to full screen.
        ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN);

        // Set the position of the window to the top left corner.
        posX = posY = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // If windowed then set it to 800x600 resolution.
        screenWidth  = 800;
        screenHeight = 600;

        // Place the window in the middle of the screen.
        posX = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - screenWidth)  / 2;
        posY = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - screenHeight) / 2;
    }

    // Create the window with the screen settings and get the handle to it.
    m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, m_applicationName, m_applicationName, 
                            WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP,
                            posX, posY, screenWidth, screenHeight, NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);

    // Bring the window up on the screen and set it as main focus.
    ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(m_hwnd);
    SetFocus(m_hwnd);

    // Hide the mouse cursor.
    ShowCursor(false);

    return;
}


void SystemClass::ShutdownWindows()
{
    // Show the mouse cursor.
    ShowCursor(true);

    // Fix the display settings if leaving full screen mode.
    if(FULL_SCREEN)
    {
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);
    }

    // Remove the window.
    DestroyWindow(m_hwnd);
    m_hwnd = NULL;

    // Remove the application instance.
    UnregisterClass(m_applicationName, m_hinstance);
    m_hinstance = NULL;

    // Release the pointer to this class.
    ApplicationHandle = NULL;

    return;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT umessage, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(umessage)
    {
        // Check if the window is being destroyed.
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }

        // Check if the window is being closed.
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);     
            return 0;
        }

        // All other messages pass to the message handler in the system class.
        default:
        {
            return ApplicationHandle->MessageHandler(hwnd, umessage, wparam, lparam);
        }
    }
}
```

I can provide any other files needed.

Comment: where did you move the camera?

Comment: I just added that file.  It is in systemclass under SystemClass::Run().  The camera's location is actually updated in SystemClass::Frame().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem.  A few things weren't updating correctly, and then when I fixed that I noticed the camera was jumping.  I just decreased the move speed from there and it works now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is: **Debug!**

Hard to say what is wrong exactly. Anything can be.

"Nothing rendered" bugs mostly only possible to solve using graphics debugger. Just pick your favorite one:

- [Visual Studio Graphics Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh315751.aspx) (included since version 2012 and higher)
- [NVIDIA Nsight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html) (for NVIDIA GPUs)
- [AMD GPU PerfStudio 2](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-perfstudio-2/) (for AMD GPUs)
- good old PIX (from DirectX SDK)

Until you run into debugging we can only guess.

My guess is transformation matrices: probably, after moving camera, view or projection matrix (or both) are not updating properly, so your model appearing somewhere where you cannot see it.

**How to debug HLSL part.**

Run your app under graphics debugger and inspect shaders. Step trough shader code, watch variables for correctness. Review buffers contents. See at final render target.

**How to debug C++ part.**

Let's assume, that, via graphics debugger, you've found incorrect view matrix in vertex shader. So, you will want to track C++ code path, from matrix creation in `m_Camera`, to feeding matrix to shader's constant buffer inside `m_TextureShader`, and find where matrix becomes corrupted. Algo:

1. set debug breakpoint inside camera class in function that responsible for matrix update/recalculation (`CameraClass::Render()`).
2. move camera in application
3. breakpoint must be hit
4. watch class fields, local variables and resulting matrix, when it created. Check that its values are correct. Put more breakpoints if needed  and step one-by-one
5. track, in which function, matrix goes, after current function returns
6. debug that function as described in (4)
7. repeat (5) and (6) until you find matrix corruption or until feeding to constant buffer

P.S. In your code snippet I've recognized rastertek tutorial sample. Patterns are well recognizable. My best advice, for the first time, when you learning: don't try to copy-modify-debug somebody else's code. But, instead, read it and write your own from scratch.

Happy coding!

Comment: I have VS 2010, so I do not have Visual Studio Graphics Debugger.  When I try to run my application with PIX, it just crashes and PIX gives me an error log:

http://snipt.org/Affib4

I am not totally copying the rastertek tutorials:  I am using them as a base for learning, but I am modifying them as I go.  When I get further I am going to write my own, using their code as a reference.

Comment: Any ideas?  I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: There is nothing more I can help you, because such bugs can only be located in debugger. Did you checked my guess of matrix corruption in C++ part of code? (see my instruction in answer). Next, you cannot use PIX, but did you tried NVIDIA Nsight (for NVIDIA GPUs) or AMD GPU PerfStudio 2 (for AMD GPUs)? Also [Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads) available now for testing for free, even Ultimate edition, which includes Graphics Debugger.

Comment: Another thing is that if debugging/profiling tools crashing, there may be hidden bugs in your code. This bugs not appearing to be destructible for now, but in future they can lead to strange behavior in your program. These problems may include using uninitialized variables, heap corruption, etc. So take your time and review your code in general, and of course under debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Just some suggestions, not sure if this can help, but you can have a try.

Set the camera position on the negative part of Z-axis and facing to the origin since DirectX use a left hand system.

in constructor of CameraClass

```
m_positionX = 0.0f;
m_positionY = 0.0f;
m_positionZ = -5.0f;
```

in Camera Render function

```
// Setup where the camera is looking by default.
lookAt.x = 0.0f;
lookAt.y = 0.0f;
lookAt.z = 0.0f;
```

your code may also work, but don't set the camera position and lookat too near. or you will only see the inner part of your mesh.

The following line does not make sense, what's the logic here?

```
lookAt = position + lookAt;
```

If you want the update the lookAt position based on the camera's movement, you can define a ahead vector, transform it by the camera's rotation matrix and add it to lookAt as below.

```
// Create the rotation matrix from the yaw, pitch, and roll values.
D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&rotationMatrix, yaw, pitch, roll);

D3DXVECTOR3 vWorldAhead;
D3DXVECTOR3 vLocalAhead = D3DXVECTOR3( 0, 0, 1 );
D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &vWorldAhead, &vLocalAhead, &rotationMatrix );
lookAt = position + vWorldAhead;

D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&up, &up, &rotationMatrix);

// Finally create the view matrix from the three updated vectors.
D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&m_viewMatrix, &position, &lookAt, &up);
return;
```

Since you already set the Up vector to (0, 1, 0), so the Up vector and Ahead vector will keep orthogonal after apply the rotation matrix.